# opencv cvSaveImage() saves RGB jpg image in BGR format

Tags: opencv

I am converting my bgr image to rgb image and then saving it to disk, but the saved image is not in rgb format.

```
IplImage* opencvImage_temp = cvCloneImage(inputImg);
cvCvtColor(inputImg,opencvImage_temp, CV_BGR2RGB );
opencvImage=cvCreateImage ( cvSize(480,320), opencvImage_temp->depth, opencvImage_temp->nChannels );
cvResize(opencvImage_temp, opencvImage);
cvSaveImage("stream.jpg",opencvImage_temp);
```

Please help me , if anyone of you faced this issue before.

Comment: please, switch to opencv's c++ api. (also, all images *are* bgr in opencv, not rgb)

Comment: Yes I know that, my concern is to save the image in RGB format on the disk. Do you know how to achieve that. Thanks for answer

Comment: not with openCV. try some extension specialized library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're over-thinking the problem. Let OpenCV take care of the conversion for you. Try this experiment (in C++!):

```
Mat blueImage(200,300, CV_8UC3, Scalar(255,0,0));
imshow("Blue Image", blueImage);
imwrite("blueOut.jpg", blueImage);

Mat blueSaved = imread("blueOut.jpg");
imshow("Saved Blue Image", blueSaved);

Mat redImage;
cvtColor(blueImage, redImage, CV_BGR2RGB);
imshow("Red Image", redImage);
imwrite("redOut.jpg", redImage);

Mat redSaved = imread("redOut.jpg");
imshow("Saved Red Image", redSaved);
```

If you look at the first line, we're clearly creating an all-blue image in BGR format. The window "Blue Image" confirms this.

When we save the BGR image as a jpeg, OpenCV automatically converts that BGR image to RGB before saving. You can confirm this by going to the directory containing your executable and opening "blueOut.jpg" using any image viewing software.

Now if you look at the creation of `redImage`, all I'm doing is converting the BGR image to RGB and viewing it. Surprise, it's red! And even when we save it, OpenCV dutifully reverses the order of the channels and the saved image "redOut.jpg" is red.

The end result of all of this is, let OpenCV work for you. You don't have to do conversions to output RGB images. Oh, and use the C++ API.

Comment: Thanks for such nice explanation, actually I was fetching image from opencv and was showing this inside a gtk window, thats why I was doing the conversion and I thought to save the converted image to the disk.